# Returning a single record from four table JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I'm trying to return distinct records based on the tb_images._id from MySQL combining the content of four tables. When I run my version I get thousands of records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tb_images._id, tb_images._photographer, tb_images._attributed, tb_images._ignore_photographer,
    tb_images._origtitle, tb_images._origdate, 
    tb_images._series,tb_images._show_desc, 
    tb_images._desc, tb_images._phototype_abbrev, 
    tb_images._phototype, tb_images._size,tb_images._sitter, 
    tb_photo_outlets._name, tb_techniques._abbrev, 
    tb_photographers._fn,tb_photographers._sn

FROM tb_images
    LEFT JOIN tb_photo_outlets ON tb_images._source = tb_photo_outlets._id
    LEFT JOIN tb_techniques ON tb_images._phototype_abbrev = tb_techniques._abbrev
    LEFT JOIN tb_photographers ON tb_images._photographer = tb_photographers._code
WHERE tb_images._id IN (' . $pv_ids . ')
ORDER BY FIELD(tb_images._id,' . $pv_ids . ');';
```

$pv_ids = 47416,86084,107283,118473,29571,9408,86088

Any advice appreciated.

I've attempted different JOINS and the use of DISTINCT but neither have solved the issue.

Comment: Does each `LEFT JOIN` produce 1 row at the most, or more than one?

Comment: Is that because there are multiple photo outlets and multiple techniques and many photographers? Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: The Impaler.
Thanks for responding.
Yes there is only a single matching record in tb_techniques, tb_photo_outlets and tb_photographers. tb_images contains all the images and the captions are constructed from the values in the other three tables.

Comment: RiggsFolly - Thanks for the reformatting.

Comment: Can you produce a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk) with the schema and some example data

Comment: RiggsFolly - Hi. I've never used DBFIDDLE.